# 'Missing Permissions' even though Bot has Administrator permissions and highest role in the server

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am making a bot with discord.py and I am implementing a kick command, here is my default code:

```
if msg.startswith(".kick"):
  author = message.author
  to_kick = message.mentions[0]

  role = get(message.guild.roles,name="Katana")

  broken_kick = msg.split(" ")

  if len(broken_kick) < 3:
    reason_ = None
  else:
    reason_ = ' '.join(broken_kick[2:])

  if role in author.roles:
    await message.channel.send(f"Kicking {to_kick} with a reason of '{reason_}'")
    await to_kick.kick(reason=reason_)
  else:
    print(str(role),str(author.roles),str(to_kick))
```

The katana role has all the permissions in the channel, and the person who is giving the command (I) also have the katana role and am the owner. When I try to kick, it gives me this error message: `discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013) Missing Permissions`. I have seen a few posts which say that it cant kick people with a role higher than its, but I don't think that's the issue here

As requested, here is the whole error message:

```py
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 452, in on_message
    await to_kick.kick(reason=reason_)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/member.py", line 568, in kick
    await self.guild.kick(self, reason=reason)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/guild.py", line 1997, in kick
    await self._state.http.kick(user.id, self.id, reason=reason)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 248, in request
    raise Forbidden(r, data)
discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions
```

Can someone please tell me where I went wrong? Any help would be heavily appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post the *whole* traceback.

Comment: sure just a second

Comment: i just edited the post

Comment: You cant kick the owner of a server, if thats what you are trying to do.

Comment: no i am just trying to kick a normal member, one with lower permissions

Comment: Does the user your trying to kick have role lower or higher than bot? That can cause issues too

Comment: no, the user i was trying to kick had a lower permission

Answer (score 0):

1. The error 'Missing Permissions' shows up when the discord.Client (your bot) does not have the permissions. So ensure that your bot has the admin permissions (or even something lower, like kick members). The recommended way to  do this is in your OAuth2 link, so that someone adding your bot to their server only needs to authorize it and need not give any roles manually.
2. On another note, I noticed you have a few flaws in your bot that make it less robust. Here they are:

- Not every server (maybe not even your own) will have only the Katana role serving as the role with kicking permissions. So, instead of using Katana as a check to whether the user has permissions, try:

```
if (author.guild_permissions.kick_members) :
    await message.channel.send(f"Kicking {to_kick} with a reason of '{reason_}'")
    await to_kick.kick(reason=_reason)
else :
    await message.channel.send("You don't have the permission!")
```

- You expect a message similar in syntax to `.kick <member> <reason>` but the main problem is that you do not strictly expect your `<member>` to be the second argument (since you're just scanning the entire message for mentions and returning the first one). The problem with this is that if the author sends a message, say, `.kick misconduct @user#1234` your bot will react so:
  `Kicking @user#1234 with a reason of @user#1234`. Not a very big problem but certainly confusing. A way to avoid this is

```
broken_kick = msg.split(" ")[1:] # can remove first element because it is sure to be .kick
if (f"{to_kick.mention}" in broken_kick) : 
    broken_kick.remove(f"{to_kick.mention}")
reason = "".join(broken_kick)
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! Sorry for the late reply!